# how i can disable the approval email at the time of first time login in joomla

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, joomla-extensions, joomla-component, joomla-community-builder

Here is the message that i got when a new user first time login

Your registration process is not yet complete! Please check again your email for further instructions that have just been resent. If you don't find the email, check your spam-box. Make sure that your email account options are not set to immediately delete spam. If that was the case, just try logging in again to receive a new instructions email.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Users->User Manager on the admin side. Click Options in the upper right. You are likely wanting to change "New User Account Activation" to "None". This will allow them login immediately after sign-up without checking their email.

I'm not sure that this will retroactively activate anyone that has already signed up, so if that is an issue, you would want to activate them manually using the User Manager. (You would want to see green checks in the "Enabled" and "Activated" columns for the users to be able to login.

Comment: I appreciate your answer.But it did not work for me.After doing that still i got the confirmation email when i logged in first time.Thanks for your reply